# Form validation CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, validation

I'm having trouble doing data validation. I want to add to the data in table_class, the subject_id column and the class_name column. input data has a condition that for the subject_id  and class_name must not have the same data in table. if using validation is_unique can't check 2 fields.

table_class

| id | subject_id | class_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Algorithm |

for example: if I enter `subject_id=B` and `class_name=algorithm` or `subject_id=A` and `class_name=Big data`, then the data will be stored in the database. But if I fill in `subject_id=A` and `class_name=algorithm`, a validation error will appear.

How to validate this error?

Comment: Please give the errormessage and the the table description...

Comment: I want to display an error in form validation like this: subject_id and class_id already exist, and the data cannot be saved in the database